# How to use SSHPASS with rsync and SSH in an automated shell script?

Tags: ssh, rsync, sshpass

I'm copying images from another PC every 3 hours. But recently I encountered an error.
When I try to `ssh` to that PC I get this:

```
Unable to negotiate with 192.xxx.xx.xx port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

I searched for a solution for this error and I found this:

```
-oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

If I try to run that in the terminal with `ssh`, the error disappears, but I'm looking to have this work in a script.
This is what I came up with:

```
sshpass -p ${pass} rsync -v --include="*/" --include="*.png" --exclude="*" --no-o --no-g --no-perms --omit-dir-times ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 ${usr}@${servip}:
```

But I got this errorP:

```
Unexpected remote arg: user@xxx.xxx.xx.xx:/home/nwpops/wrfcntl/plots/op01/20220419_0000/d01/f00000/pcpacc1h_mm.png
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1372) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using rsync's `-e` or `--rsh` option to pass the ssh command? `sshpass -p "${pass}" rsync -e 'ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1' -v ...`

Comment: Or just this: `-e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"`

Answer (score 1):

So I've been researching this for several days, since there are many different solutions floating around but none of them seemed to work in my automated rsync backup script for [SlickStack](https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/bash/ss-remote-backup.txt).

This is the function I came up with ultimately:

```
function ss_rsync_backup {
    rsync -acz --mkpath --rsh="sshpass -p ${RSYNC_PASSWORD} ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${RSYNC_USER}" "$@"
}
```

And then use like this:

```
ss_rsync_backup /var/www/html/ "${RSYNC_USER}"@"${RSYNC_REMOTE_HOST}":slickstack/"${SITE_DOMAIN_EXCLUDING_WWW}"/html/
```

It's actually kind of insane how sensitive and complex the rsync command syntax is... I think they are kind of stuck with regard to backwards compatibility, so it is what it is.

Unlike other Linux utilities, if you are browsing various options/flags on StackOverflow and trying to combine them it might break things... the formatting of the syntax is very important.

Also be sure to `apt install sshpass` before use this script.

Note: you should NOT requrie the `-e` flag if you are using the formatting I used above.

Thanks: https://itecnote.com/tecnote/r-how-to-pass-password-automatically-for-rsync-ssh-command/